# nodemon cant reload my project: always have error EADR in use

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I was making a very simple node server, and run it with `nodemon app.js`. The server starting success, but if I make changes in the script and save it, I have an error about `EADDR in use`. The node process was not killed or exited. in package.json I put the `delay` parameter for nodemon.

My app.js (clean) it not work:

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const PORT = 5000;

    const routes = require('./Settings/routes')

    app.use(express.json())

    routes(app)

    app.listen(PORT, ()=>
        console.log('Сервер работает на порту ' + PORT)
    )
```

My app.js (with improvements), but it not work either

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const PORT = 5000;

    const routes = require('./Settings/routes')

    app.use(express.json())

    routes(app)

    app.listen(PORT, ()=>
        console.log('Сервер работает на порту ' + PORT)
    )


    // first create a generic "terminator"
    terminator = function(sig){
            if (typeof sig === "string") {
                    console.log('%s: Received %s - terminating sample app ...',
                        new Date(Date.now()), sig);
                    process.kill(process.pid, sig)
            }
            console.log('%s: Node server stopped.', new Date(Date.now()) );
    };

    const arrayOfSignals = [ 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM']


    // then implement it for every process signal related to exit/quit
    arrayOfSignals.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            process.on(element, function() {
                    console.log('Ожидаем перезапуск процесса')
                    terminator(element)
            });
    });
```

I tried with `process.exit()` and with `process.kill()`

I thought that nodemon must work from beginning...What I do not do right?

UPD: console error:

```js
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
    at Function.listen (/chokoapp/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/chokoapp/backend/app.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Node - v  : 14.17.0

Comment: Can you post the console error as well?

Comment: @RukshanJayasekara I put it in my question

Answer (score 3):

A simple fix that worked when I had a similar issue is to delay Nodemon's restart in package.json file:

```
nodemon --delay 500ms app.js
```

This seems to give a little time for ports to be correctly released.

Answer (score 2):

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

This means the port `5000` is already in use. So you can't use this port for your express server.

I'll suggest 2 solutions.

**1. Change the port number of the express server.**

`const PORT = 5000;` to something like `const PORT = 8000;`

**2. Kill the process which is using port 5000.**

First, you would want to know which process is using `port 5000`

`sudo lsof -i :5000` OR in Windows CMD, `netstat -ano | findstr 5000`

this will list all **PID** listening on this port, once you have the **PID** you can terminate it with the following:

`kill -9 {PID}`

Comment: On first run all ok. The problems begin when i try save changes, and nodemon trying reload project. The port 5000 used by my node app, another processes not ude this port

Comment: Then it seems you are trying to start the server again while it's already running.

Comment: Yes....my question ..why nodemon cant exit or kill node process befor run attempt (

Comment: What nodemon does is restart the server when the code changes. What is the command you are using to start the server at first?

Comment: i was try 1) nodemon app.js 2) pm2 start "node app.js" --watch